# lapply in R, same function different arguments

Tags: r, class, lapply, multiple-arguments

I have two fit objects reg and reg1.

I want to run summary() on each without having to re specify whole thing, just the arguments.
What is an easy way to do this in **general** in R? I tried something like this:

```
lapply(c(reg, reg1), function(x) summary.default(x))
```

but note that

```
> class(reg1)
[1] "glm" "lm" 
> class(reg)
[1] "lm"
```

regardless of the general solution asked for, is it the different classes that are messing with this particular case? is it the format of the first lapply arg.?

Edit: 
Figured it out

```
lapply(list(reg, reg1), summary)
```

but why does it need to be list()?
I see that list(reg) calls lm.
why is c(reg, reg1) not an appropriate way to pass arguments?

Thanks

Comment: `lapply(list(reg,reg1), summary)` should work, giving you a list of length 2. What's the problem that you are having?

Comment: To make it more clear, what is messing with this particular case is the use of `c()`, use `list(reg, reg1)`, like @RLave said in his comment.

Comment: thanks for that. But why is c() not appropriate?

Comment: @FacundoFerreira - well by definition lapply only works on lists

Comment: @MatthewR That is not true. For example, `lapply(1:2, function(x) x + 1)` is perfectly valid code, despite the fact that `1:2` is not a list. `lapply` starts with an `l` because it *returns* a list.

Comment: @FacundoFerreira `glm` and `lm` objects are lists internally. `c` combines these two lists (each containing multiple elements, see `str(reg1)`) into one list, which is obviously not what you want. You want to *put* them into a list and that's why you need `list`.